# Why four conserved quantities instead of three to call this system "completely integrable"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The system which describes a rigid-body in four-dimensions is written as

$$
\begin{align*}
    \dot{x}_1 &= x_2x_3A_{32} + x_5 x_6 A_{65}\\
    \dot{x}_2 &= x_1 x_3 A_{13} + x_4 x_6 A_{46}\\
    \dot{x}_3 &= x_1 x_2 A_{21} + x_4 x_5 A_{54}\\
    \dot{x}_4 &= x_3x_5 A_{35} + x_2 x_6 A_{62}\\
    \dot{x}_5 &= x_3 x_4 A_{43} + x_1 x_6 A_{16}\\
    \dot{x}_6 &= x_2 x_4 A_{24} + x_1 x_5 A_{51}
\end{align*}
$$ where $A_{ij} = \lambda_i - \lambda_j$ and these $\lambda$s denote physical constants. This is from page $309$ of: https://zero.sci-hub.tw/643/fc90d8b8b70badd0ce0b6bc1c45ac5ed/adler1982.pdf#view=FitH

Adler writes that there are four conserved quantities:

> ...by setting these four invariants equal to a constant, generically
> intersect in the affine part of an Abelian variety of genus 2.

which refers to the invariant described $(6)$ on page $299$ and the other three, including the Hamiltonian, on page $298$.

Since the system is defined on $so(4)$ which has six degrees of freedom, then I had thought that only **$3$** conserved quantities were needed to call this system "completely integrable" since $\frac{6}{2} = 3$. This comes from what I read about the maximum number of conserved quantities: [half the dimension of the phase space](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/chapter.pdf) bottom of page 49. Why do they need $4$ of them?